# Would creating a portal-like app give me trouble when submitting on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

The app is a small portal from which you can view/buy videos, view/buy songs, play/buy games and view/buy epubs.

Would Apple view this app as competing or being similar to the App Store or iBooks and thus reject it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to use in-app purchase for it? If so, you should have less of a problem. But yes, as mentioned, they *might* view it as competition, but typically they are quite lenient if they still make profit from the in-app purchases. Also, since you are selling more than one type of media, it cannot really be viewed as direct competition.

Comment: Yes, it the payment mechanism is through in app purchases. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **StoreKit** for purchases, you should be fine as long as you don't create functionality that is the same or similar to the functionality provided by the integrated apps. You have to have a unique difference ("Use the special gmail-functions" was enough for google mail but that was Google).

If your app uses another payment mechanism (PayPal, ...) it will be denied. You have to use StoreKit / iTunes and give apple 30% of the revenue.